# How to loop through a self referential model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm new to ruby on rails and I'm building a wiki app where the navigation is to be sorted by categories. Each article, or page, can belong to a category, but a category can also be a sub-category of another category. An administrator will be able to create new categories or sub-categories calling for a dynamic approach to generating a list of categories for the menu. I'm trying to figure out how to display a list of all parent categories and all of their children and grandchildren categories where the menu would look something like this:

```
 1. Parent1
    1.a Child1
    1.b Child2
 2. Parent2
    2.a Child1
       2.a.1 Grandchild1
```

I currently have some nested loops in my view which kind of work, but it's not dynamic since it will only show the first two generations, and I would have to repeat the code to show more.

Model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sub_categories, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "category_id"
  belongs_to :category, class_name: "Category", optional: true
end
```

Controller:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @sorted_categories = Category.order(:sort_number).where("category_id IS NULL")
        @sub_categories = Category.order(:sort_number).where("category_id IS NOT NULL")
    end
end
```

View:

```
<% if @categories.nil? %>
  <h3>There are currently no categories.</h3>
<% else %>
  <ul>
    <% @sorted_categories.each do |c| %>
    <li><%= c.name %><%= link_to 'Move Up', categories_move_up_path(c) %> Sort:<%= c.sort_number %></li>
    <% @sub_categories.each do |s| %>
      <% if s.category_id == c.id %>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <%= s.name %><%= link_to 'Move Up', categories_move_up_path(s) %> Sort:<%= s.sort_number %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you can use [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem for tree structures. It has many features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [acts_as_list](https://github.com/brendon/acts_as_list) gem, it does exactly what you want.

It will define a `parent_id` column, and each object will be a child of a parent, so that you can create infinite tree of categories ans sub-categories.

It also provides the methods to move objects up and down.